# Get Azure access token through Web Proxy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are using **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** API to acquire access token from Azure AD.

We have the requirement API call should pass through web proxy. We couldn't find any relevant sample code.

Is there any option to achieve  this requirement. Please find the code snippet used.

```
string accessToken = string.Empty;
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(authority, subscription.TentantId));            
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(subscription.ClientId, subscription.SecertKey);
            var result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientCredential);
            accessToken = result.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that this library does not support setting of IWebProxy object - I couldn't find a way. However there seem to be two solutions:

1) You can set global proxy, however this is recommended practice. See below:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("10.0.0.1:1234");
```

2) You can request the token via REST api call and set proxy manually to your HttpRequest

```
POST "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantName}/oauth2/token"
```

this could be tricky in some cases (jwt client assertion type etc..)

see this example: https://github.com/mattleib/o365api-as-apponly-webapp/blob/master/AccessMailboxAsApp/AccessMailboxAsApp/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L558