# how to acquire Msgraph Token with Proxy settings C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azureportal

I am using a C# daemon service application to read calendar events of particular users from the Azure portal.

Now, the below code is working fine in my pc

```
private async Task<string> **AcquireToken**()
{
AuthenticationResult Tokenresult = null;
app = CreateConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder(); 

string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{ApiUrl}.default" };
            
try
{
    Tokenresult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();
    return Tokenresult?.AccessToken;
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    utils.logger.logEvents("The application doesn't have sufficient permissions "
     + " Did you declare enough app permissions during app creation?"
     + "- Did the tenant admin grant permissions to the application?");
    utils.logger.logEvents(ex.Message);
}
catch (MsalServiceException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
{
    utils.logger.logEvents("Scope provided is not supported. Invalid scope. The scope has to be of the form https://resourceurl/.default"
        + "Mitigation: change the scope to be as expected");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    utils.logger.logEvents("error in AcquireToken " + ex.Message);
}
return string.Empty;
```

}

But the same code is not working (giving Time out error) in another PC that is configured with Proxy settings.

Here I don't know how to configure the above code to use the Proxy server in order to reach the azure portal.
( I have googled many hrs but NO luck)

so please advise How to configure the "AcquireTokenForClient()" method to use proxy settings.

Huge thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250977/get-azure-access-token-through-web-proxy?answertab=votes#tab-top) should be instructive.

Comment: You said the code works fine in your pc but down in another pc which has proxy setting, so I think the error comes from the pc itself, just like your pc is connected to the normal network and the other pc is disconnected from the network, so how to make the latter one  get service from the internet? And maybe I misunderstand yours. Sorry for that.

Comment: @AllenWu, I got the token, but when I try to get the calendar event it says,      "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",  I am passing Scope  parameter as "./default" while getting the token

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed `ApiUrl` is `https://graph.microsoft.com/`?

Comment: yes.,  request.AddParameter("scope", $"{ApiUrl}.default");, I included that too. but no luck, Do I need to specify the resource value along with scope while getting the token?

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed Decode your access token in https://jwt.io to see what the `aud` claim is.

Comment: @AllenWu, aud claim : 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 ,
but in the working scenario (local testing with my company tenent id), if I decode the token I see "https://graph.microsoft.com" something like this.

Comment: @SaddamBinSyed The id for Microsoft Graph should be `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` rather than `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`. Are you sure `ApiUrl` is `https://graph.microsoft.com/`?

Comment: yes. 100%  sure, "https://graph.microsoft.com/"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229498/discussion-between-allen-wu-and-saddambinsyed).

Answer (score 0):

The later versions of MSAL support using your own httpClientFactory see https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/httpclient which enables you to configure the underlying proxy settings

If you have an Authenticated proxy then you need to be careful what credentials your app will present (as you probably don't want to hard code them like the example) eg if the app runs as local system those are the creds it will present etc.